# Changing tasks order

Tags: lists, enumerate, tasks

When I use tasks environment, I get

```
(a) item 1             (b) item 2             (c) item 3
(d) item 4             (e) item 5
```

Is possible to change the order to

```
(a) item 1               (c) item 3            (e) item 5
(b) item 2               (d) item 4
```

Comment: `tasks` was designed for lists counting horizontally (like in your first case). If you want them counting vertically, standard lists should do just fine. i.e., don't use `tasks`.

Comment: You could use `\begin{multicols}{3}\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]\item...\end{enumerate}\end{multicols}` with the `multicol` and the `enumitem` packages loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `enumerate` environment inside `multicols`. Additionally, use `\usepackage{enumitem}` to customise the labels. Here, I've used `[label=(\alph*)]`.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{3}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
        \item item 1
        \item item 2
        \item item 3
        \item item 4
        \item item 5
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I should have posted my comment as an answer, would have been 8 seconds faster :)